# Customizing first listbox item

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, styling

could you help me with styling of ItemTemplate for listbox. I need to display data as in an image. So first item should be customized (big picture, others fonts, etc.) and below it others items.
So, how i can do it, or i should separate controls, for first item and others?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find the following useful "Implementing Windows Phone 7 DataTemplateSelector and CustomDataTemplateSelector" :-

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataTemplateSelector. But you need to have a property in your item to tell that it's the first item. Go through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) for reference.